# Travelling to the UK on an accompanied child visa

Tags: uk

I am travelling to the UK for a school tour and I have an accompanied child visa, as I am under 18, which clearly states that it's only valid if accompanied by my teacher. However I wish to stay in the UK longer. Can I leave the UK alone a few days after my teacher has left?

Answer (score 9):

**No** you **shouldn't** do so, even if someone suggests you can. Some people like to suggest that just because UK does not have exit immigration nobody will notice this, **don't listen to them**.

The adult listed on your visa is supposed to take care of your well being throughout the trip and not just facilitate you with an entry. If you remain there and the said adult leaves the UK you/they might have trouble going to the UK again.

---

Personal Experience:

After our first trip to the UK when we were checking in at the airport to go back home the check-in officer noticed that our child's surname was different from ours and looked at our passports for a few more minutes. Then she asked: *Do you happen to carry his birth certificate with you?* I had it and presented it immediately. She saw it and said *perfect* and gave us our boarding passes.

This incident does not directly relate to your situation but it does relate to the fact that they really care about child visitors even on exit.  Even when me and my wife were both listed on his visa and were with him we were still asked for a certificate. Imagine being really unaccompanied on exit.

Comment: @I.ayub You would be in breach of the Immigration Rules,  V4.13  https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules it's a violation of the rules to leave the child in the UK after entering the country as it's required that the child is accompanied by the individual named in the visa's endorsement. You agreed to this condition when the visa was issued.

Comment: @Traveller V4.13 only specifies what a child's visa must say for the visa to be valid. V4.11 is more pertinent, but only says that "adequate arrangements must have been made for their ... care in the UK"; it doesn't require that the accompanying adult remain in the UK.  I'm not saying that it is allowed for the adult to leave, but the citation you've offered does not support your assertion.